# Convert a HTML 5 Template to Angular

Tags: angular

Well, i have a template with some javascript files declared in bottom of index.html and some CSS in top. Like jQuery, Datatable, Select2 and more.

I know that Angular don't know how to manage it because are out yours boundaries. In a file javascript called main.js i have the following:

```
$("#someintput").val("hi world");
$("#datatable#").Datatable();
```

This works **sometimes**. Datatable is rendered sometimes, but sometimes not. Angular intefere in this process ? What is the correct way to make angular work this javascript and css files from template ?

Answer (score 1):

You must tell the CLI that you want to use these files, open the `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`(newest Angular version) file and look for the apps.styles and apps.scripts section

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [],
```

then you need to modify it to look like this:

```
"styles": [
   "path/to/your/css/here.css",
   "another.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "path/to/your/js/here.js",
   "another.js"
],
```

I hope that this will help you

Any CSS files you want to add that you won’t be referencing from your modules directly, and any javascript files that you won’t be importing into your TypeScript files. When you compile, they become part of the bundles.

Comment: but if a add jquery-datatable in scripts tag inside angular.json will work without conflict ? why angular have a special angular-jquerydatatable if i can use the native jquery-datatable ?